# Google Drive iOS SDK: Display Cancel Login Button

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, google-drive-api

I'm working on a iOS Application and i use Google drive to access my files , login and listing file works fine , but I'm just asking how i can add a cancel button on the Login interface provided by Google drive sdk see the Image bellow

[image]

As,you see there are no way to do a `cancel` or a `go back` button.

Here Is my code

```
// verify if the user is already connected or not 
    - (void)checkIfIsConnected
    {
        // Check for authorization.
        GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =
        [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                              clientID:kClientID
                                                          clientSecret:kClientSecret];
        if ([auth canAuthorize]) {
            [self isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:auth];
        }else
        {
            [self ConnectToDrive];
        }
    }

    - (GTLServiceDrive *)driveService {
        static GTLServiceDrive *service = nil;
        if (!service) {

            service = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
            // Have the service object set tickets to fetch consecutive pages
            // of the feed so we do not need to manually fetch them.
            service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
            // Have the service object set tickets to retry temporary error conditions
            // automatically.
            service.retryEnabled = YES;
        }
        return service;
    }

    -(void) ConnectToDrive{
        SEL finishedSelector = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);
        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController =
        [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                   clientID:kClientID
                                               clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                           keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                   delegate:self
                                           finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
        [self.fileManagementViewController presentModalViewController:authViewController animated:YES];
    }

    // Action executed after finishing the Authentication
    - (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
          finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                     error:(NSError *)error {
        [self.fileManagementViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        if (error == nil) {
            [self isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:auth];
        }
    }

    - (void)isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth {
        [[self driveService] setAuthorizer:auth];
        self.isAuthorized = YES;
        [self loadDriveFiles];
    }
```

so what wrong ??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please follow the steps -

[image]

Go to--> `GTLSource->Common->OAuth2->Touch-->GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[self setUpNavigation];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@   {NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 63)];
[self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                             action:@selector(cancelGdriveSignIn:)];    
UINavigationItem *navigItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Google Drive"];
navigItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelItem;
naviBarObj.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigItem,nil];    
}

 -(void)cancelGdriveSignIn:(id)sender
 {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
 }

-(void)setUpNavigation // Default Method Available 
{
 rightBarButtonItem_.customView = navButtonsView_;
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem_;
}
```

Once you add the above changes in the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m and run it. you will get cancel button like this-

[image]

Happy Coding......!!

Comment: thanks for you reply , but can you give me the exact path to the GTMOAuth2Authentication.m class , because for me i found it in GTL source/Common/OAuth2  but i did not find the viewDidLoad  Function on it

Comment: I do not have  GTMOAuth2Authentication.m on the GTLSource->Common->OAuth2->Touch but i have only GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m and i did that in it but nothing changed

Comment: @hatimhaffane buddy check here---- GTLSource->Common->OAuth2->Touch-->GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m. See my updated answer..

Comment: please see my Edit , may be i missing some thing

Comment: @hatimhaffane please follow the path....GTLSource->Common->OAuth2->Touch-->GTMOAuth2Authentication.m. Edit the code in GTMOAuth2Authentication.m.

Comment: i did that but i did not get the navigation bar

Comment: BTW there are no need to the diagram i know where is the class that you told me and i edit it but nothing happened , thanks for your help

Comment: the code that i show to you exist on my project class not on the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m , do you have any idea how i can debug the sdk calls from my project ?

Comment: it's works Bro :) i just opened the workspace containing my Project and the SDK project and clean it then build it thanks a lot  for your patient

Answer (score 12):

Change sources - bad way. Here is my solution. Works on iPhone and iPad

```
 GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                                                clientID:GoogleDriveClientID
                                                                                            clientSecret:GoogleDriveClientSecret
                                                                                        keychainItemName:GoogleDriveKeychainItemName
                                                                                       completionHandler:authCompletionHandler];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authViewController];
    navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [rootController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(didCanceledAuthorization)];
        authViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        authViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
        authViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Google Drive";
    });
```

Comment: Much better this way!
I'm using Pod for Google-SDK, so I can't edit the sources this easy.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift Version - For the new users** : This will not hide the Google logo under the navigationBar

Extend the class `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`

```
extension GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
{
    public override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cancelItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelGdriveSignIn))
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = cancelItem
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Google Drive"
    }

    func cancelGdriveSignIn()
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

AND add a navigation Controller before returning your AuthController

```
private func createAuthController() -> UIViewController {
    let scopeString = scopes.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    let controller = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: scopeString, clientID: kClientID, clientSecret: nil, keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName, delegate: self, finishedSelector: #selector(ViewController.viewController(_:finishedWithAuth:error:)))
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    return navController
}
```

Works like charm.

Comment: I just needed to change the title and it worked only when invoked in viewDidAppear() not in viewDidLoad() in the above code. Otherwise thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Agree with @nab0y4enko - change the SDK is bad.

1.The current GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch add 2 buttons to the navigation bar.
So I had to create new class "CustomAuthViewController" which inherited from GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch and override setUpNavigation with no implementation.This implementation will not add those 2 buttons

```
@implementation CustomAuthViewController

- (void)setUpNavigation
{
    // Don't call super becasue it is adding ugly Back / Forwad image buttons
}

@end
```

2.We can set the cancel button without declare and change the navigation width, and without dispatch async thread. We can do it by edit the navigationBar.topItem instead of the navigation item.

```
UIViewController* navController = [self createAuthNavigationController];
[self.originViewController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

- (UIViewController *)createAuthNavigationController
{
    // Create CustomViewController which inherited from GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
    CustomAuthViewController * authViewController = [[CustomAuthViewController alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                      clientID:kClientID
                                  clientSecret:kClientSecret
                              keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                      delegate:self
                              finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    // Create navigation VC
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authViewController];

    // Set as Modal form -> not full screen in IPad
    [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    // Add cancel button to the navigation
    navController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                          target:self
                                          action:@selector(buttonCancelTapped:)];;
    // Set Title
    [navController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"Google Drive"];

    return navController;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Immi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476256/1040347/) answer is good. But for those, who has iPad problem:

[image: nav Bar's width is hardcoded as 320.]

You should make the width correct, so replace the:

```
    UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., 320., 63.)];
```

with this

```
    UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 63.)];
```

Also the Google title is hidden by navigation Bar. Not good. So do the next:
In

`- (void)moveWebViewFromUnderNavigationBar` change

```
  CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0., 63., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

and in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

comment out calling of method `[self isNavigationBarTranslucent]` :

```
//    if ([self isNavigationBarTranslucent]) {
  [self moveWebViewFromUnderNavigationBar];
//    }
```

**UPD.** for interface orientation
To make the navBar change due to interface orientation, I recommend to use NSNotification Center, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681499/1040347).
As for this situation, you should do the next:

1. Implement your NavBar in @interface in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m
2. Put the notification listener in ViewDidLoad.
3. Make the navBar change.

So, let's go:

1. right under `@interface` put
   `@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationBar *naviBarObj;`
2. in ViewDidLoad:

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:)
   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
   object:nil];
3. and finally:

   ```
   -(void)deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
   {
       UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
       if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
       {
           self.naviBarObj.frame = CGRectMake(0., 0., [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 63.0);
       }
       else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
       {
           self.naviBarObj.frame = CGRectMake(0., 0., [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, 63.0);
       } }
   ```

P.S. don't forget, that you should now use `self.naviBarObj` everywhere you used `naviBarObj`. And remove the `UINavigationBar` before `naviBarObj` in `ViewDidLoad`

**UPD 2.0**

```
  - (CGRect) setNavBarWidth
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        return CGRectMake(0., 0., [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 63.0);
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        return CGRectMake(0., 0., [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, 63.0);
    }

    return CGRectMake(0., 0., [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 63.0);
}
```

And call it `self.naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:[self setNavBarWidth]];` from `viewDidLoad`, as well as

```
self.naviBarObj.frame = [self setNavBarWidth];
```

from `deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` methods then :)

Comment: good but when i move from portrait landscape the navigation bar don't take the howl screen

Comment: with this update when you change orientation the navigation bar works fine , but if you start the app on the landscape by default the navigation bar will not take the howl size :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    let finishedSelector = #selector(YourViewControllerOrAnotherObject.googleAuthViewController(_:finishedWithAuth:error:))
    let authController = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly, clientID: AppGoogleClientID, clientSecret: nil, keychainItemName: keychainItemName, delegate: self, finishedSelector: finishedSelector)
    let cancelAction = #selector(YourViewControllerOrAnotherObject.dismissGoogleAuthController)
    authController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: cancelAction)
    authController.title = "Google Authentication"

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: authController)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        // remove default rightBarButtonItem
        authController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    })
```