# presenting GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch wtih presentViewController:animated:completion

Tags: ios, sdk

I need to open google login viewController as a modal from a existing viewController. That's ok but I don't know how to add a button for closing the modal because I'm not using an UINavigationController. Anybody having this same problem?

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
        viewController = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:GOOGLE_SCOPE_YOUTUBE
                                                                  clientID:GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
                                                              clientSecret:GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
                                                          keychainItemName:GOOGLE_KEYCHAIN
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                          finishedSelector:finishedSel];

        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"es" forKey:@"hl"];
        viewController.signIn.additionalAuthorizationParameters = params;
        viewController.signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile = YES;
        NSString *html = @"<html><body style=\"font-family:Arial\"><div style=\"text-align:center;\">Cargando página para iniciar sesión...</div></body></html>";
        viewController.initialHTMLString = html;
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

thanks

Comment: See this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453691/google-drive-ios-sdk-display-cancel-login-button

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up using

```
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But this is not the perfect solution (very ugly btw and non-flat). I am wondering why the Nav Bar doesn't show up for

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Yeah, we could add the Nav Bar manually

```
UINavigationBar *navBar=[etc…
```

I think perfect solution'd be to use the new UIViewTransitions (Apple wants to force us to use this?).

Comment: Could you tell me if finishedSelector is correctly called after the successfull login?

Comment: hmmm…I think that depends on the Google View Controller Code, not the ViewController itself. Have you added the delegate correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is my re-interpretation of [Imran Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2522603/imran-khan)'s excellent answer provided in his response to this stack overflow question: [Google Drive iOS SDK: Display Cancel Login Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453691/google-drive-ios-sdk-display-cancel-login-button)

Go there and up-vote his response, I have only copied and converted.

```
if (!self.isAuthorized) {
    SEL selectorFinish = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);
    SEL selectorButtonCancel = @selector(buttonCancelTapped:);

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 63)];
    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:<<localised string for title>>];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:selectorButtonCancel];

    [navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItemCancel];
    [navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigationItem,nil]];

    [navController.view addSubview:navigationBar];

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = nil;
    authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                    clientID:kClientID
                                                                clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                            keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                    delegate:self
                                                            finishedSelector:selectorFinish];

    [navController addChildViewController:authViewController];

    [self.parentTVC presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**For clarity**, the `buttonCancelTapped:` method is as follows...

```
- (IBAction)buttonCancelTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.parentTVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
}
```

**For clarity**, the variable `parentTVC` is a public property,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewController *parentTVC;
```

and is set using a custom init method, as follows...

```
- (id)initWithParentTVC:(UITableViewController *)tvc {
    self = [super init];
    [self setParentTVC:tvc];

    return self;
}
```

This custom init method is called from the parent view controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Version - For the new users**

Extend the class `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`

```
extension GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
{
    public override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cancelItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelGdriveSignIn))
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = cancelItem
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Google Drive"
    }

    func cancelGdriveSignIn()
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

AND add a navigation Controller before returning your AuthController

```
private func createAuthController() -> UIViewController {
    let scopeString = scopes.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    let controller = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: scopeString, clientID: kClientID, clientSecret: nil, keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName, delegate: self, finishedSelector: #selector(ViewController.viewController(_:finishedWithAuth:error:)))
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    return navController
}
```

Works like charm.