# Add UINavigationItem to UINavigationController that wraps Google Drive OAuth

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, google-drive-api, google-oauth, uinavigationitem

**Goal**: For connection to iOS Google Drive, wrap the iOS Google OAuth view controller in a programmatically created navigation controller, and add a Cancel button to enable the user to cancel the Google OAuth process, should they choose to do so.

**Problem**: While I can successfully wrap the OAuth view controller in a navigation controller, I cannot seem to add a navigation item, such as the desired Cancel button.

I add a navigation controller that wraps the Google Drive OAuth view controller, as follows...

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = nil;
if (!self.isAuthorized) {
    SEL selectorFinish = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);
    SEL selectorButtonCancel = @selector(buttonCancelTapped:);

    authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                    clientID:kClientID
                                                                clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                            keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                    delegate:self
                                                            finishedSelector:selectorFinish];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    [navController addChildViewController:authViewController];

    [self.parentTVC presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

For clarity, the variable `parentTVC` is a public property,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewController *parentTVC;
```

and is set using a custom init method, as follows...

```
- (id)initWithParentTVC:(UITableViewController *)tvc {
    self = [super init];
    [self setParentTVC:tvc];

    return self;
}
```

I have attempted to add `UINavigationItem`s to the `UINavigationController` instance `navController`, however this does not work, and instead I seem to be stuck with the `UIView` with the two small buttons (< and >) in the nib file GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib, image included below...

[image: GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib]

I have read through the GTL file `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m` to attempt to see whether there is a method I could possible use or whether I can override by subclassing, but I am not confident in my attempts to do this.

My best guess is that any navigation controller wrapping the OAuth view controller set by this code from `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m`...

```
- (void)setUpNavigation {
  rightBarButtonItem_.customView = navButtonsView_;
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem_;
}
```

Assistance please?

Comment: My apologies...

Just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453691/google-drive-ios-sdk-display-cancel-login-button

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct. will be helpful to others.

Comment: Thanks @SHAD will do. I have already attempted this, but apparently I have to wait 2 days...? In the meantime, to confirm, this answer is correct and is working in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my re-interpretation of [Imran Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2522603/imran-khan)'s excellent answer provided in his response to this stack overflow question: [Google Drive iOS SDK: Display Cancel Login Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453691/google-drive-ios-sdk-display-cancel-login-button)

The `googleAuthCheck` method should be called in either the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method of the parent view controller. (I assume here a reasonable understanding of iOS Google Drive SDK, so let me know if I need to add further clarification.)

Also, albeit a small issue, using `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel` requires that only the title text of the view controller then needs to be localised (if you are implementing localisation).

```
- (void)googleAuthCheck {
    if (!self.isAuthorized) {
        SEL selectorFinish = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);
        SEL selectorButtonCancel = @selector(buttonCancelTapped:);

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

        UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:<<localised string for title>>];
        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:selectorButtonCancel];
        UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 63)];

        [navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItemCancel];
        [navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
        [navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigationItem,nil]];

        [navController.view addSubview:navigationBar];

        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = nil;
        authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                        clientID:kClientID
                                                                    clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                                keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                        delegate:self
                                                                finishedSelector:selectorFinish];

        [navController addChildViewController:authViewController];

        [self.parentTVC presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**For clarity**, the `buttonCancelTapped:` method is as follows...

```
- (IBAction)buttonCancelTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.parentTVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){}];
}
```

**For clarity**, the variable `parentTVC` is a public property,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewController *parentTVC;
```

and is set using a custom init method, as follows...

```
- (id)initWithParentTVC:(UITableViewController *)tvc {
    self = [super init];
    [self setParentTVC:tvc];

    return self;
}
```

This custom init method is called from the parent view controller.