# redraw a custom uiview when changing a device orientation

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, quartz-core

1. If I draw my chart inside `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` is just enough to set [`_chartView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw]` and this method will be called when device changes it's orienatation and it's possible to calculate f.e. new center point for my chart.
2. If I create a view like a subview using `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` and then add it in view controller like `[self.view addSubview:chartView];`. How in this case I can handle rotation to redraw my chart?

Comment: @Keenle,@Kijug when you draw using the second way you do not use drawRect method, see f.e https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart/blob/master/PNChart/PNPieChart/PNPieChart.m

Comment: + needs to call redraw method only first time when device orientation changes like drawRect does

Comment: I've updated the answer. Had to create a test project with chart control to figure out the problem. BTW the charts component is simple and great!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make your chart rendered correctly when device orientation changes you need to update chart's layout, here is the code that you should add to your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    _chartView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [_chartView strokeChart];
}
```

Comment: I believe its highly discouraged to set frame in code since auto-layouts came out, check my answer

Answer (score 42):

While a preferred solution requires [zero lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043363/218152), if you **must** trigger a redraw, do so in `setNeedsDisplay`, which in turn invokes `drawRect`.
No need to listen to notifications nor refactor the code.

**Swift**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

---

*Note:*
*`layoutSubviews` is a `UIView` method, **not** a `UIViewController` method.*

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but when I put this into my TableViewController it is not called upon rotation. Perhaps it's my target version of iOS (8.1) or something, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` is a `UIView` method, not a `UIViewController` method. You need to make a subclass of `UITableView`, not `UITableViewController`, which can be done in **IB**. You may want to read more about layoutSubviews on http://stackoverflow.com/a/5330162/218152.

Comment: Cool, thanks. My views were actually redrawing already from setting contentMode = .Redraw on the TableView in IB. The problem I had was my own fault, since corrected. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work in my testing. Orientation change does not trigger a redraw. And I am using this on a class I created that subclasses UIView

Answer (score 8):

### Zero Lines of Code

**Use `.redraw`**

Programmatically invoking `myView.contentMode = .redraw` when creating the custom view should suffice. It is a single flag in **IB** and, as such, the **0 lines of code** prefered way. See Stack Overflow [How to trigger drawRect on UIView subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9023348/218152).

Comment: Great answer, elegant and does the job, +1.

Answer (score 4):

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681304/ios-6-how-to-run-custom-code-when-orientation-changes) to learn how to receive notifications for when the device orientation changes. When the orientation does change, just call `[chartView setNeedsDisplay];` to make `drawRect:` get called so you can update your view. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the right answer, the UIView subclass shall handle this by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The code you'll add to your view controller:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    [_chartView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't called upon device rotation.

Comment: @DamienDelRusso there might be some other reason why its not being called for you on device rotation, look around

Comment: I would look, but I found out my views are redrawing with contentMode set to .Redraw. The reason it wasn't working for me was my own dumb error, since fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately some answers suggest to override controller methods, but I've some custom `UITableViewCells` with a shadow around and rotating the device stretches the cells but doesn't redraw the shadow. So I don't want to put my code within a controller to (re)draw a subview.
The solution for me is to listen to a `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` notification within my custom `UITableViewCell` and then call `setNeedsDisplay()` as suggested.

**Swift 4.0 Code example in one of my custom UITableViewCells**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

@objc func deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification(_ notification: Any) {
        Logger.info("Orientation changed: \(notification)")
        setNeedsLayout()
}
```

BTW: `Logger` is a `typealias` to `SwiftyBeaver`.
Thanks to @Aderis pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Keenle, for the above ObjC solution. I was messing around with creating programmed constraints all morning, killing my brain, not understanding why they would not recompile/realign the view. I guess because I had created the UIView programmatically using CGRect...this was taking precedence.

However, here was my solution in swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    myUIView.center = CGPoint(x: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2), y: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 2))
}
```

So relieved! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried "setNeedsDisplay" in a dozen ways and it didn't work for adjusting the shadow of a view I was animating to a new position.

I did solve my problem with this though. If your shadow doesn't seem to want to cooperate/update, you could try just setting the shadow to nil, then setting it again:

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.2 /*Total*/, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(), animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 10/10, animations:{
            // Other things to animate

            //Set shadow to nil
            self.viewWithShadow.layer.shadowPath = nil
        })
    }, completion: { finished in
        if (!finished) { return }
        // When the view is moved, set the shadow again
        self.viewWithShadow.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.descTextView.bounds).cgPath
    })
```

If you don't even have a shadow yet and need that code, here's that:

```
func addShadowTo (view: UIView) {
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize( width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
    view.layer.shouldRasterize = true
}
```